# Why KVM is called Kernel-based Virtual Machine?

Tags: virtualization, linux-kvm

I want to know how KVM stands for Kernel-based Virtual Machine. Is there any reason behind? Is it due to "OS" work on kernel position i mean ring 0 or Level 0?
Is my assumption is correct or not? If not then please explain what is the reason behind?

Answer (score 0):

In 2007 Intel and AMD created Intel VT-x and AMD-V to support [native mode virtualisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware-assisted_virtualization). Prior to this all virtualisation in the x86 architecture had been done in userspace

The user space models created a virtual ring 0 for the guest to run in. This was very computationally expensive.

With hardware assisted virtualisation this could not be directly accessed by userspace so there needed to be kernel side code to expose the /dev/kvm interface to userspace clients.

KVM simply marks the location that the heavy lifting of virtualisation is performed.

Comment: What is reason behind  the name "hardware assisted"  and KVM?

Comment: Because it is virtualisation assisted by hardware - as opposed to being entirely performed in software.